# Prevent tab key from selecting URL in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, default

I'm making a game, and there's a leaderboard. I want the user to be able to toggle the leaderboard by hitting the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. Here is my code:

```
keysPressed = {};

if(keysPressed[KEY_TAB]){
    if(leaderboard.style.display == 'none'){
        $(leaderboard).fadeIn(100);
    } else {
        $(leaderboard).fadeOut(100);
    }

    keysPressed[KEY_TAB] = false;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    keysPressed[event.key.toLowerCase()] = true;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    keysPressed[event.key.toLowerCase()] = false;
}, false);
```

**Note: `leaderboard` is just `document.getElementById('leaderboard')`**

This all works fine, but whenever I hit the tab key, the webpage (I'm using Chrome) automatically selects/deselects the `URL` bar. Is there a way I can prevent the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key from doing this, or do I need to switch to a different key? Here is an screenshot demonstrating my problem:

[image: Problem]

`JavaScript` is prefered, since I am rather new to `jQuery`, but I am willing to go either.

Thanks in advance~

Comment: OffTopic: consider using `$(leaderboard).is(":visible")` [:visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But is there a reason to switch?

Comment: @freedomn-mm, it seems to be working fine as of now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

From MDN :

> The preventDefault() method of the Event interface tells the user
> agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default
> action should not be taken as it normally would be.
>
> The event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its event
> listeners calls stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation(),
> either of which terminates propagation at once.
>
> As noted below, calling preventDefault() for a non-cancelable event,
> such as one dispatched via EventTarget.dispatchEvent(), without
> specifying cancelable: true has no effect.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key == "Tab") {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why does the `preventDefault` need to be with `keyUp` as well?

Comment: Okay. This works, thanks! I was going to mention that it should be specific to the `tab` key, but I just saw your edit! Thanks again! I'll accept in 5 mins